# Templated function pointer with arguments as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I can't get my code to compile. I want to be able to declare a function that takes another function (or a class with operator() defined, or lambda expression) as parameter, and this function has template arguments as well. Here's an example of what I want to do:

```
template <class T, T F> 
T execF(T a, T b) 
{ 
    return F(a, b); 
}

template <class T>
T add(T a, T b) 
{ 
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{ 
    std::cout << execF<int, add>(3,4) << std::endl;
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this in C++14?

Comment: What is the reason you want to pass the function as a template argument, instead as of a normal function argument? Because with a function argument it would be *very* easy in any version of C++ (and also mirror how the C++ standard library handles callable arguments).

Comment: Change `template<class T, T F>` to `template<class T, T(&F)(T,T)>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
template <class T, T F(T, T)>
T execF(T a, T b)
{
    return F(a, b);
}
```

If you want to omit all template parameters, I suggest to stick with Some Programmer Dude's comment and accept the function as a function parameter:

```
template <typename T>
T execF(T a, T b, T f(T, T))
{
    return f(a, b);
}

template <typename T>
T add(T a, T b) { return a + b; }

int main(int , char **)
{
    auto x = execF(41.8f, 0.2f, add); //all params deduced in both functions
    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    x = execF(27, 15, add); //idem
    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works, but is there a way to invoke it like:

execF<add>(3,4)

Without having to specify the first argument of the template?

Comment: I don't think so (at least until c++14). I edited the answer, anyway.